# Deleting files smaller than a certain size with batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Is there any way to delete all files in a specific folder that are smaller than `x MB` using a batch file?
 I looked at the [forfiles](http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html) command, but it seems like with it you can only delete files that are older than `x days`.

Comment: @KenWhite I saw that post, but I had absolutely no idea what it was, and how I could modify it to fit my own needs.

Comment: You modify it to suit your needs by changing the single number that indicates the file size and changing the path used to point to your folder. Why is that difficult to modify for you?

Comment: @KenWhite Because I've never used Batch/DOS before, and just wanted to use it for deleting all these small files without having to learn it... sorry

Comment: @SkeletonBow See my answer below

Comment: Sorry. We're not here to be your code writing service. If you *don't want to learn it*, hire a contractor to write it for you.

Comment: @SkeletonBow, the answer in the duplicate question is essentially the same as the one Alex provided below.

Comment: @Squashman I'm sorry for causing all of this commotion. Should I delete this question? It doesn't look like it's going to be useful for anyone

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is possible by using a `for /f` statement. The below script will all delete files below `100KB` *(100,000 bytes)* Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal
:: Size is in bytes
set "min.size=100000"

for /f  "usebackq delims=;" %%A in (`dir /b /A:-D *.*`) do If %%~zA LSS %min.size% del "%%A"
```

Comment: Your `DIR` command will also list folders with periods in them. Use the `/A-D` option to exclude folders from being listed.  Personally I would just use a basic `FOR` command as that will not list folders.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It works really well. I couldn't find out how it assumes to carry out the command in the current folder (is it the `dir /b`?). It deletes itself as well, but that doesn't really matter – I'll be copying and pasting the file to any folder I want to carry it out in.